# knowing if a HTML tag has a text node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

given the 2 alternative

```
<div class="no-text example">
  100
</div>

<div class="with-text example">
 <span class="surprise"> 50 </span>
 100
</div>
```

I would like to get the number inside `.example` in both cases, with the same selector OR somehow knowing the difference between `.no-text` and `.with-text`

doing `$(".example").text()` will give me `50 100`

currently I am experimenting with `.clone().children().remove().end().text()` but I need to somehow know it is `.no-text` and `.with-text`

Comment: `$('.example').children().length`?

Comment: @AndreasEriksson that could work, I will test on more test cases

Answer (score 1):

I dont knkow how you want your data, but if you for example want an array of all text node texts, then you could do it like this.

Create an empty array, then loop over all the `.example` elements and check if each "this" has a span inside of it.

if you think that a "surprise" element can be anything then for example add `|| $(this).children("p").length` on the right hand of the `if()` check

```
var textArray = []

$(".example").each(function(){
    if($(this).children("span").length) {
        textArray.push($(this).text())
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the number directly under `.example`, try this:

```
$(".example").contents()
    .filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3;  //text node
    }).each(function () {
        console.log(+this.nodeValue.trim());
    });

//100
//100
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/hjamxbc3/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and store the values in an array object:

```js
var o = {};

$(".example").each(function() {
  o[$(this).attr("class")] = $(this).map(function() {
    return $.trim(this.textContent).split(' ');
  }).get();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="no-text example">
  100
</div>

<div class="with-text example">
  <span class="surprise"> 50 </span>
  100
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but I created a little jsfiddle that might be able to help: http://jsfiddle.net/mxr6eddm/

```
$(".example").each(function () {

    $("#output").append($(this).text());

    if ($(this).hasClass('with-text')) $("#output").append(" - with text");
    else $("#output").append(" - no text");

    $("#output").append("<br>");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('div').each(function(){
var valueOfDiv;
if($(this).find('span').length > 0)
{
  valueOfDiv = $(this).find('span').text();
}
else{
  valueOfDiv = $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following

```
$('.example').each(function(){
   if ($(this).find('span').length > 0) {
     var span = $(this).children('span');
     alert('Has child :' +span.text());
   } else {
     alert($(this).text());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter()` in conjunction with `.contents()` :

```js
var which = [];

$('body > .example').contents().filter(function() {
    if(this.nodeType === 3 && this.parentNode.classList.length > 1 ){
          which.push(this.parentNode.classList[0]);
    }
});

$('#elements').html(JSON.stringify(which));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="no-text example">100</div>

<div class="with-text example"><span class="surprise"> 50 </span>100</div>

<div id='elements'></div>
```